# How to constraint function generic type according to a parameter's property?

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have this enum:

```
enum ItemType: String {
        case image
        case movie

        var rawValue: String {
            switch self {
                case .image: return String(kUTTypeImage)
                case .movie: return String(kUTTypeMovie)
            }
        }
    }
```

and this function inside a class

```
func items<T>(for type: ItemType, completion: ([T]) -> Void) where T: NSSecureCoding {}
```

Now what I would like to achieve is that if the ItemType is .image I would like the completion to be inferred as of type `([UIImage]) -> Void` otherwise if it is .video I would like it to be inferred as `([URL]) -> Void`

Is this possible in any way in Swift? Or what would be an alternative approach to make the completion type infer according to the type provided.

**Additional details:**

The body of the function uses NSItemProvider loadItem instance method whose closure returns any type conforming to NSSecureCoding. So as long as I can give a type like that I don't care about what type specifically it is.

```
func items<T>(for type: ItemType, completion: ([T]) -> Void) where T: NSSecureCoding {
        itemProviders(for: [type]).forEach { itemProvider in
            itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: type.rawValue, options: nil, completionHandler: { (item: T, error: Error!) in

            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not just write two functions (that possibly overload each other)?

Comment: @matt In the future I'll have another 4 or 5 types in this :) and besides it's interesting to comprehend generics fully.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this because the parameter `type` is evaluated at *runtime*, while at *compile time*, `T` needs to be inferred.

A workaround is to separate this into two methods:

```
func itemsForImages(completion: ([UIImage]) -> Void) { ... }
func itemsForMovies(completion: ([URL]) -> Void) { ... }
```

And then determine which method to call:

```
switch itemType {
    case .image:
        itemsForImages { images in ... }
    case .movies:
        itemsForMovies { urls in ... }
}
```

Another alternative is to have a closure of type `([Any]) -> Void` and the caller needs to cast the parameter to the correct types, but this is not so type safe.

Comment: Is there any chance I can provide a protocol and maybe some extensions to make it inferable at compile time? maybe even by changing the function declaration.

Comment: @Fawkes I think you are having an XY problem here. You shouldn't really try to unite all these things into one method. You need to do different things to the images array and the URLs array, right? You handle them differently, right? So they should be called in a switch or if statement. Depending on what `itemType` is, handle the result from the completion handler differently.

Comment: I'm using them in combination with NSItemProvider which has a closure which can return the type you are expecting if it is NSSecureCoding. So basically if I can infer the type T somehow out of my enum types I can just pass it directly to NSItemProvider.loadObjectFor ... So, I'm not really interested in knowing specifically what I'm deserialising as long as the caller knows what it expects.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the body of the function

Comment: @Fawkes Whatever you do, you must have a switch or if statement somewhere. You can change the method signature of `itemFor` to accept a meta type to infer `T`, and then cast the `NSSecureCoding` parameter to `T`. But to determine what meta type you pass requires an if or switch statement. This is not something that can be done with generics alone.